# Android Jetpack Compose Robolectric createComposeRule java.lang.AbstractMethodError

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, robolectric

I am trying to test compose with Robolectric. I created an example test:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)
class ProductDescriptionComposeTest {

    @get:Rule
    val composeTestRule = createComposeRule()

    @Test
    fun testShowMoreText() {

    }
}
```

And added to `build.gradle`:

```
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
testImplementation "org.robolectric:robolectric:4.8.1"
testImplementation 'androidx.test:core:1.4.0'
testImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:1.2.1'
debugImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest:1.2.1'
```

when I run it, I get:

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class androidx.compose.ui.test.TestMonotonicFrameClock does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract kotlin.coroutines.CoroutineContext$Key getKey()' of interface kotlin.coroutines.CoroutineContext$Element.
at kotlin.coroutines.CoroutineContext$plus$1.invoke(CoroutineContext.kt:33)
at kotlin.coroutines.CoroutineContext$plus$1.invoke(CoroutineContext.kt:32)
```

at the line:

```
val composeTestRule = createComposeRule()
```

I tried to search, but all example codes contain the same and work

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error as I had made a mistake in including the main Compose dependencies.

I WRONGLY had:

```
testImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
```

Whereas I should have had

```
implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
```